# cant access base class property in derived class in C#

Tags: c#, properties

Here is my base class

```
public class AttachmentBase
{
    public AttachmentBase ();

    public string[] Content { get; set; }
    public string FileExtension { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my derived class

```
public class Attachment:AttachmentBase
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and here is how I instantiate new attachment in mvc controller

```
var attachmnet = new Attachment();
```

but when i want to access the `FileExtension` or other property that are in base class I dont have  access to them. Everything is public but I do not  have access to them.

I should say the base class in in another dll but I have added the reference to project.

What is problem that i cant access base class property in derived class?

Comment: I've only seen this in cases where the code hasn't been fully recompiled. Try cleaning your project / solution and compiling again.

Comment: Could you post the *exact* error message, copy-pasted from Visual Studio?

Comment: Alternatively, I see that your constructor for `AttachmentBase` does not have a body -- that will be rejected by the compiler. -- https://repl.it/C39W

Comment: there is no error , i simply dont have access to base class member.

Comment: How do you recognize that you have "no access" to that property? Provide some sample code where you describe and prove that behavior.

Comment: thank you . when i wanted to access the Content Property then i got message the AttachmentBase is another dll that is reference in .... but it was referenced . i removed the reference and add it again and rebuild my project , now it works. i can see right now why c# is not that productive as it is advertised

Comment: I'm afraid you are blaming C# for something that is not its fault...

Comment: @Arash I had this _exact_ same problem and mine was because, like in your example, my `AttachmentBase` class was in a totally different assembly than my `Attachment` class, which was still in a different assembly than my base project C# code where I had `var attachmnet = new Attachment();`. My base project had a reference to the assembly where `Attachment` was defined, and the assembly where `Attachment` was defined had a reference to the assembly where `AttachmentBase` was defined, but my base project did not have a reference to the assembly where `AttachmentBase` was defined. Adding will fix

Comment: I had the same issue, which was caused by partial class which didn't inherit the base class. To be more precise, I had a blazor component with custom `.cs` file : the class in code behind inhertited the base class, whereas the razor markup had no `@inherit` tag.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply create a base class and a derived class, there's no way you can have this issue. From what you said, it seems this happened because you created the base class in a project (= assembly = dll) and the derived one in another one, and instead of making this second project reference the first one, you made it reference a copy of a compiled dll. This way of course you won't get the changes of the first project in realtime.

When a project references another one, Visual Studio always recompiles everything that's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Did Your check namespace?
Because "AttachmentBase" class is under "System.Net.Main" namespace,and maybe you forget to add correct project namespace that "AttachmentBase" is in it.

Answer (score -2):

remove the reference to Attachment base dll in project , add it again , and rebuild solution .

i can see why c# cant be wise choose for productivity.

Comment: it is clear that you are frustrated, but please try to not turn your question and answer into a rant in disguise.